# Why do photos not add in iOS 9 using PHPhotoLibrary performChangesAndWait?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In iOS 8.4, the following code works fine. 
In iOS 9, it fails, with a useless error (-1 null NSCocoaErrorDomain or whatever).

```
bool success = [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChangesAndWait:^{
            ...
            newChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:container.filePath]];

        if( !newChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset ) {
            DDLogWarn(@"addToCameraRoll: WARNING, PLACEHOLDER COULD NOT BE CREATED: %@", container.filePath);

            if( perAddFailBlock )
                perAddFailBlock(container.filePath, true, container.isVideo, true);
            continue;

        } else {
            if( container.creationDate )
                newChangeRequest.creationDate = container.creationDate;
            [placeholders addObject:newChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset];
            bytesRequired += container.size.integerValue;
        }
    }

    PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest* albumChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:self.album];
    [albumChangeRequest addAssets:placeholders];
    ...
} error:error];
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8.x, Photos framework doesn't care about the name of the file. 
In this code here:

```
newChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:container.filePath]];
```

... filePath can be anything.

In iOS 9.0 this is no longer true. 
In iOS 9.0, the change request is generated, and it appears to have a valid placeholderForCreatedAsset. But when you run it in performChanges block, it fails.

**This is because it seems that iOS 9.0 cares about the filename: files must have a valid filename extension like .jpg**

Here is the code I used to fix this iOS 9 regression. Note that although it's hardcoded to jpg here, I tried hardcoding it to PNG and jpgs still added fine. So it seems it just needs ANY photo extension to work. Laaaame.

```
        if( !container.filePath.pathExtension || [@"" isEqualToString:container.filePath.pathExtension] ) {
            NSString *newName = [container.filePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"jpg"]; // doesn't matter that it is hardcoded to jpg
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:container.filePath toPath:newName error:nil];
            container.filePath = newName;
        }
```